# SELECTING data via C# from a table valued function (MSSQL) causes a CREATE FUNCTION statement

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using C# (.net 4.6.1) to access a MSSQL 2018 database.
Sometimes when I select data from a table valued function, the (C#) program seems to stop and when I look in the 'running queries' there is a suspended query that CREATES the function I'm selecting data from (CREATE FUNCTION.....).

*Here is how I look at running queries*

```
SELECT 
    syp.spid AS SesID
    ,syp.hostname
    ,syp.program_name
    ,syp.loginame
    ,sqltext.TEXT
    ,syp.login_time
    ,req.session_id
    ,req.status
    ,req.command
    ,SUM(req.cpu_time) AS cpu_time
    ,SUM(req.total_elapsed_time) AS total_elapsed_time
FROM DB.sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY DB.sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
INNER JOIN DB.sys.sysprocesses syp ON syp.spid = req.session_id
WHERE loginame <> ''
GROUP BY
    syp.spid 
    ,syp.hostname
    ,syp.program_name
    ,syp.loginame
    ,sqltext.TEXT
    ,syp.login_time
    ,req.session_id
    ,req.status
    ,req.command
```

The way I select data in C# looks like this:

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DB.._f_po_lines(@refRecHead) a ", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refRecHead", refRecHead);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        { .....
```

I tried to monitor the db activity via the profiler, but I don't see the CREATE FUNCTION statement there (maybe because that is hidden, but I have not found how I can show these statements via the event selection) so I can't figure out if this happens every time I select data from a table valued function.

Right now the only solution to make the (C#)program work again is deleting the function in the management studio and re-creating it.

I hope I gave all relevant information and have some questions:
- Is it expected behavior for MSSQL to re-create the function when you select data from it?
- If not, what could be the reason for this happens?
- If yes, how can I make it faster so the (C#) program does not slow down to the point where it reaches the timeout limit?

edit : the (simplified) function looks like this (not too interesting, just selecting data, but I find it more easy to work with functions in C#)

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[_f_po_lines] (@RefRecHead bigint) RETURNS @ret TABLE

(
    RowNr int
)

AS

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ret

    SELECT 
        t.RowNr
    FROM DB..PURCHTABLE t
    WHERE 
        t.REFRECID = @RefRecHead

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: It could help if we knew the function's code.

Comment: You need to use the `statement_start_offset` and `statement_end_offset` columns of `sys.dm_exec_requests` to extract the current statement text from the `CREATE FUNCTION`. See [the documentation for an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql).

Comment: @sticky bit I added the functions code (a simplified version)

Comment: Aside: do yourself and all future maintainers a favor by using complete, readable names -- there's no tax on them and SQL Server allows up to 128 characters. There's only so much of `PURCHTABLE`, `REFRECID` and `_f_po_lines` one can take before breaking down. (I realize you may not have a choice in the case of legacy designs.) Also, do not use `db..purchtable` if the function is *in* `db` -- this creates an unnecessary remote reference. Also also, this function (while simplified) can easily be written as an inline table-valued function, which performs much better.

Comment: @Dan, I'm not sure how this will help me find out if there is a re - creation of the function happening every time? If I read correctly, this is 'only' used to find out what is blocking the query. I would like to know why it even is fired.

Comment: If you check `sys.sql_modules`, you'll see the definition of the function is there as a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement. This is the "text" SQL Server presents; it does not mean it's actually executing the `CREATE FUNCTION` itself. Hence the need for the offsets to find out which statement *inside* the function is blocking.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks for your suggestion. the 'db' is just used in this example. We have several db's on one server that work together, so we need to add the real db name (hidden in my example) other than that, we use the table names / field names that are used in the db. I can't change that (because it is not my software db that I am selecting data from, in fact it is Dynamics AX).

Comment: I see something strange in the next query `SELECT TOP * FROM DB.._f_po_lines(@refRecHead) a` , should the number of rows in the TOP go? independent that the result of the function is a table variable

Comment: @Esteban, you are right, I missed the 1. The function is used several times but in this form I only want the first row.

Comment: If you find performance issues are "fixed" by recreating the function, you may be suffering from a bad cached execution plan -- the results of this function will depend critically on the parameter supplied. You'd need to gather execution plans to be sure, but the queries could benefit from an `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR <value>/UNKNOWN)` clause to tune this, or even an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the top-level query (but that has more impact).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into the actual function and execution plans. You answered my question by stating the CREATE text is not actually what is happening when I look at my running queries.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I re wrote the function as inline table-valued function, so I will see what happens now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JeroenMostert I found out the query text I see in the 'running queries' output  is actually not what is happening when you select data from a function. 
So my initial question is answered, now I only need to find out what is blocking the function from returning data.

Right now I have changed the actual function to a inline table-valued function (because that performs better) and will monitor if the issue of a suspended query happens again. 
If that happens again, I will try to find out what is blocking it by the suggestion @DanGuzman made.

Thanks a lot!